# How to sequence commands in callback hell

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, nightwatch.js

The code below takes a screenshot and cuts off a certain element passed as a CSS selector.

```
const imageLib = require('imagelib/imageLib');

withoutElementScreenshot.prototype.command = function (selector, filename, cb) {
    var self = this;

    function execute(client, selector, filename, cb) {
        client.element('css selector', selector, function (element) {
            client.elementIdLocationInView(element.value.ELEMENT, function (location) {
                client.elementIdSize(element.value.ELEMENT, function (size) {
                    client.takeScreenshot(filename, function () {
                        imageLib(filename).pngToData(function () {
                            for (var x = location.value.x; x < size.value.width + location.value.x; x++) {
                                for (var y = location.value.y; y < size.value.height + location.value.y; y++) {
                                    this.setPixel(x, y, 255, 255, 255, 255);
                                }
                            }
                            this.toPng(filename, function () {
                                client.log('Screenshot without element would be saved into ' + filename);
                                cb();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

How do I pass an array of selectors to cut them all off? I cannot iterate through the array since the takeScreenshot function is in between callbacks.

Comment: have you tried sending a comma-separated list of selectors?

Comment: Yes, in this case client.element finds the first element from the list and passes it to elementIdLocationInView and further. Only the first element is getting cut off from the screenshot.